# scanf vs cin: string as integer processing

Tags: c++, scanf, cin, visual-c++-2010

I have an input string "0100"

Why does `scanf("%i", &n);` returns 64 and `cin >> n`; gives me 100? Why does cin think in decimal values and scanf in octal?

Comment: Use `%d`, then `scanf` would also work in decimal. `%i` means "C integer literal rules", essentially.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> For the **`i`** specifier:   Any number of digits, optionally preceded by a sign (`+` or `-`).
>   Decimal digits assumed by default (`0-9`), **but a** `0` **prefix introduces octal digits** (`0-7`), and `0x` introduces hexadecimal digits (`0-f`). - [scanf - C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

Since you prefixed `100` with a `0` then it's read as an octal rather than decimal.

#### Update:

> Would you mind to add `cin >> setbase(0) >> n` to your answer? - Nicky C

```
//                           cin input:  0100
//                         base         | n ='s
//                        ----------------------
cin >> setbase(0)  >> n // *see below   | 64
cin >> setbase(8)  >> n // octal        | 64
cin >> setbase(10) >> n // decimal      | 100
cin >> setbase(16) >> n // hexadecimal  | 256
```

* <sub>Calling `setbase( x )` where `x` does not equal `8`, `10` or `16` is the same thing as calling `setbase(resetiosflags(ios_base::basefield))`. Where the input to `cin` would be read as a `C` literal, meaning the prefix of `0` would be octal, `0x` would be hex and no prefix would be decimal.</sub>

Comment: Would you mind to add `cin >> setbase(0) >> n;` to your answer?